# Adding a hook to Vim's default buffer

Tags: vim

I want to configure Vim such that when the [No Name] buffer is open, the syntax is set to markdown. Is this possible? I couldn't see such kind of hook in Vim's help.

I'm using Vim 7.3, compiled with `--with-features=huge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned [on the vim tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_type_plugins#Setting_a_default_filetype):

```
" default filetype
let g:do_filetype = 0
au GUIEnter,BufAdd * if expand('<afile>') == "" | let g:do_filetype = 1 | endif
au BufEnter * if g:do_filetype | setf markdown | let g:do_filetype = 0 | endif
```

> Why the need to use a global variable, and not set the filetype immediately, is to my understanding, because the buffer hasn't been fully created when the autocmd is triggered.

Comment: Thanks! This works for gui. I altered GUIEnter to BufWinEnter to make it work in the terminal.